# How to have nest NavigationView and NavigationStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My goal is to pop to feature-root view, i.e.:

1. ContentView

   1. Feature1View
   2. Feature2View

      1. Feature2_1View

         1. Feature2_1_1View

            1. Feature2_1_1_1View <= should return to Feature2View.

The problem are:

1. Feature2View initialize viewmodels and use `.environmentObject` to pass the viewmodels:

   1. Feature2_1ViewModel
   2. Feature2_1_1ViewModel
   3. Feature2_1_1_1ViewModel

Using `environmentObject()` is necessary. This is because the `navigationDestination(for:,destination:)` will call View init() multiple time, so initializing observable object in a view can be costly.

2. Nested `NavigationStack(path:)` can't pass `.environmentObject()`

```
// ContentView.swift
NavigationStack {

   // Feature2View.swift
   NavigationStack(path: $path) {

     // Feature2_1View.swift <= will throw error.
   }
   .environmentObject()
}
```

The current solution is to use NavigationView at the top.

```
// ContentView.swift
NavigationView {

   // Feature2View.swift
   NavigationStack(path: $path) {

     // Feature2_1View.swift
   }
   .environmentObject()
}
```

3. Swipe back gesture do not work when `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`.

The current solution is

```
extension UINavigationController {
    /// allow to .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) without losing swipe back gesture.
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

The problem is:

1. Swipe back gesture is disabled from `Feature2View -> ContentView`. Not sure why.
2. Swipe back gesture from `Feature2_1View -> Feature2View` then try to go back to `Feature2_1View` will cause a freeze.

I tried 2 things:

1. Feature 1 -> initialize `@StateObject ViewModel` at each view.
2. Feature 2 -> initialize `@StateObject ViewModel` in `Feature2View` then pass it to `Feature2_1View`.

=== TL:DR === for easier reading, I have prepared the [github repository](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/NavigationStackExample)

**Feature 1**

1. `@StateObject ViewModel` initialized at each view. `Feature1View` have `Feature1ViewModel`, `Feature1View` have `Feature1_1ViewModel`

Feature1.swift

```swift
enum Feature1ViewRoute {
    case Feature1_1
}

class Feature1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()
    
    @Published var departure: Station?
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct Feature1View: View {
    @StateObject private var feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel
    
    init(feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel = Feature1ViewModel()) {
        self._feature1ViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: feature1ViewModel)
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature1")
            Text("departure \(feature1ViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                feature1ViewModel.departure = Station(name: "Lebak Bulus Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set departure")
            }
            NavigationLink(value: Feature1ViewRoute.Feature1_1) {
                Text("Go to Feature1_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature1ViewRoute.self) { route in
            switch route {
            case .Feature1_1:
                Feature1_1View(feature1ViewModel: feature1ViewModel).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feature1_1.swift

```swift
enum Feature1_1ViewRoute {
    case Feature1_1_1
}


class Feature1_1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentStation: Station?
    
    let id = UUID()
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}


struct Feature1_1View: View {
    @ObservedObject var feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel
    
    @StateObject private var feature1_1ViewModel: Feature1_1ViewModel = Feature1_1ViewModel()
    
    init(feature1ViewModel: Feature1ViewModel = Feature1ViewModel()) {
        self.feature1ViewModel = feature1ViewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature1_1View")
            Text("departure \(feature1ViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Text("current station \(feature1_1ViewModel.currentStation?.name ?? "")")
            
            Button {
                feature1ViewModel.departure = Station(name: "Fatmawati Indomaret Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set departure")
            }
            
            Button {
                feature1_1ViewModel.currentStation = Station(name: "Fatmawati Indomaret Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set current station")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(value: Feature1_1ViewRoute.Feature1_1_1) {
                Text("Go to Feature1_1_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature1_1ViewRoute.self) { route in
            Feature1_1_1View().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

**Feature2**

1. initialize all `@StateObject ViewModels` in `Feature2View` then pass it to `Feature2_1View`

Feature2.swift

```swift
enum Feature2ViewRoute {
    case Feature2_1
    case Feature2_2
}

class Feature2ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    
    @Published var departure: Station?
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct Feature2View: View {
    @StateObject private var feature2ViewModel = Feature2ViewModel()
    @StateObject private var feature2_1ViewModel = Feature2_1ViewModel()
    @StateObject private var feature2_1_1ViewModel = Feature2_1_1ViewModel()
    @StateObject private var feature2_1_1_1ViewModel = Feature2_1_1_1ViewModel()
    
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature2")
            Text("departure \(feature2ViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                feature2ViewModel.departure = Station(name: "Lebak Bulus Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set departure")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(value: Feature2ViewRoute.Feature2_1) {
                Text("go to Feature 2_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature2ViewRoute.self) { value in
            Feature2_1View(
                feature2ViewModel: feature2ViewModel,
                feature2_1ViewModel: feature2_1ViewModel,
                feature2_1_1ViewModel: feature2_1_1ViewModel,
                feature2_1_1_1ViewModel: feature2_1_1_1ViewModel
            )
//                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Feature2_1.swift

```swift
enum Feature2_1ViewRoute {
    case Feature2_1_1
}

class Feature2_1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()
    
    @Published var currentStation: Station?
    
    init() { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
    
    deinit { print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function) \(id.uuidString)") }
}

struct Feature2_1View: View {
    @ObservedObject var feature2ViewModel: Feature2ViewModel
    @ObservedObject var feature2_1ViewModel: Feature2_1ViewModel
    @ObservedObject var feature2_1_1ViewModel: Feature2_1_1ViewModel
    @ObservedObject var feature2_1_1_1ViewModel: Feature2_1_1_1ViewModel
    
    init(
        feature2ViewModel: Feature2ViewModel = Feature2ViewModel(),
        feature2_1ViewModel: Feature2_1ViewModel = Feature2_1ViewModel(),
        feature2_1_1ViewModel: Feature2_1_1ViewModel = Feature2_1_1ViewModel(),
        feature2_1_1_1ViewModel: Feature2_1_1_1ViewModel = Feature2_1_1_1ViewModel()
    ) {
        self.feature2ViewModel = feature2ViewModel
        self.feature2_1ViewModel = feature2_1ViewModel
        self.feature2_1_1ViewModel = feature2_1_1ViewModel
        self.feature2_1_1_1ViewModel = feature2_1_1_1ViewModel
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature2_1")
            Text("departure \(feature2ViewModel.departure?.name ?? "")")
            Text("current station \(feature2_1ViewModel.currentStation?.name ?? "")")
            Button {
                feature2_1ViewModel.currentStation = Station(name: "Fatmawati Indomaret Grab")
            } label: {
                Text("set current station")
            }
            NavigationLink(value: Feature2_1ViewRoute.Feature2_1_1) {
                Text("go to Feature 2_1_1")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Feature2_1ViewRoute.self) { _ in
            Feature2_1_1View(
                feature2ViewModel: feature2ViewModel,
                feature2_1ViewModel: feature2_1ViewModel,
                feature2_1_1ViewModel: feature2_1_1ViewModel,
                feature2_1_1_1ViewModel: feature2_1_1_1ViewModel
            )
//                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NavigationStack replaces NavigationView and you should never have 2 in the same stack. It would be better to hear your question towards you end goal vs trying to make up a buggy solution.

Comment: @loremipsum would you please help me with the correct pattern?

Comment: There is no way to help without an Minimal Reproducible Example of your issues, emphasis on Minimal and Reproducible. But start by getting rid of any extra NavigationStack/View there are very few exceptions for the 1 per app rule.

Comment: @loremipsum please kindly check. I prepared 2 coding style Feature 1 initialize `@StateObject ViewModel` in each view. Meanwhile, Feature 2 initialize `StateObject ViewModels` in parent view then pass it to child view. I prepared the [github repository](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/NavigationStackExample) for better clarity.

Comment: I’ll try to look at it in detail later but you can’t inject into the environment from a subview especially when using navigationDestination. It has to go into the Stack. 2. StateObject is for initializing and ObservedObject is for passing around. 3. Overriding the init of a View is hardly ever efficient, let SwiftUI manage that. Also, and this is an opinion I think you are taking VMs way to far these are way to many they are terrible performance wise, so much so that Apple has replaced ObservableObjects in iOS 17

Comment: @loremipsum , I am curious about `I think you are taking VMs way to far these are way to many they are terrible performance wise`, could you suggest better approach in using VMs?. Anyway, please kindly check [this repository](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/UIKitNavigationExample). I prepared SwiftUI + UIKitNavigation and the viewmodel only gets initialized once now.

Comment: Like I said that is an opinion and usually out of scope for SO. That would be a much longer discussion. But if you look at Apple’s documentation you’ll get what I am saying. Apple talks extensively about managing model data, UI State, etc. VMs as a references are usually reserved for special circumstances. This seems quite excessive especially when I see Feature2_1View that doesn’t even fit into the definition of a VM. I don’t look at repositories BTW, SO has to be all inclusive. I answer on here for free and as a distraction.